# TensorFlow False Detection

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have trained TensorFlow model with 200 car images, they can success detection:

[image]

But, when there is no car in the image, a false car detection occurs, why?, how i can prevent this?:

[image]

Comment: A simple method is to set a threshold to filter not really high confidence(>0.8)

Comment: Sometimes the confidence is 0.97 without a car

Answer (score 2):

Your model needs to be trained with negative examples (i.e. images without any cars in them). It needs to understand that it is possible that an image doesn't have any car.

Further, it looks like the model has understood some unrelated features as car features. E.g.: the parking lot area. To avoid this use random erasing augmentation while training model.

[Random erasing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04896) -Inspired by the mechanisms of dropout regularization, random erasing can be seen as analogous to dropout except in the input data space rather than embedded into the network architecture. By removing certain input patches, the model is forced to find other descriptive characteristics.

Comment: Thanks Abhi25t, in negative examples what is the TAG for the XML file to training process?

Comment: @NELSONRODRIGUEZ Sorry, I have not worked with XML files. That depends on your specific data/method. If you mean - how will the bounding box look like for negative data - answer is `[]` i.e. empty list